# Method Not Allowed Error after redirecting in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, payu

So what is going on is I have integrated the PayU payment gateway in my angular app. It has a success and failure url to which it gets redirected to according to the payment response. Now those urls are client's url where the client receives the response from PayU after payment success/failure. It is sent as a POST with few query parameters that are to be parsed.

Now the problem is that since the request is a POST request on a localhost url(with the same port on which I am already running the app), the console says that 'Method is not Allowed'.

The success url is http://localhost:8005/#!/payment/success

My app is running on http://localhost:8005 (which is the same).

Now I tried to define the url in app.js so as to receive the response as follows -

```
.state('successScreen',{
    url:'/payment/success/',
    templateUrl:'partials/successScreen.html',
    controller:'paySCtrl'
});
```

but it doesn't work.

when I am redirected to the url(http://localhost:8005/#!/payment/success) after payment, I am getting that 'Method Not Allowed' error.

The same url is working with GET request though but it cannot be a GET request as it is a response from third party so cannot change it from POST to GET.

So can anyone please help me with how can I overcome this thing or a work around maybe?

Comment: Problem is server side but you haven't identified anything about server language used or shown any server side code or configuration detail

Comment: @charlietfl I am running my app using npm start(on nodejs).. So I'll have to configure the node server file then to overcome this issue?

Comment: you need a route that handles the post

Comment: @charlietfl Can you please explain that with some reference or example..i didn't quite get u there.. I have added a state in my app.js for the url, which i have shown in the above code..

Comment: That is an angular state which runs in the browser. Your issue is how your server side routing works and needs to handle a post request. `npm start` doesn't tell us anything about how you have node set up

Comment: @charlietfl so will the dependencies in package.json help u in understanding my node setup?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133204/discussion-between-naman-gupta-and-charlietfl).